# What if musical piece not ended with tonic chord?

Tags: theory, chord-theory, classical-music, pop-music

I've a chord progression **G, A, Bm, A**, repeating itself throuh whole song in a key of **B minor**....i mean How it will affect the listener and how they feel ..

Comment: Bored?.........

Comment: Why would this be in the key of B minor? Harmony wise you don't have anything pulling you that way. Depending on the melody, I may be inclined to say your song is modal (probably G Lydian) rather than tonally in B minor. Just because you use a set of notes in a scale does not mean it's tonally in that key.

Comment: @dom I've composed melody having tonal center B...n then harmonizing it with thse chords...

Comment: The progression you have isn't based in tonal harmony and is just planing so I doubt you have a tonal center of B.  Again it could be modal in which case the final would be where you are at rest. It's a small, but important distinction. Another thing to note the 3rd of a G major chord is B so based on the progression without the melody  I can't see how you are reaching this conclusion especially since the harmony does not really do anything tonally significant. Thinking about it now, what chord do you want to end on if there is one more chord at the end?

Comment: Having played it with different voicings, it gravitates to D for me, not surprising, as G and A are IV and V of D, and Bm is the relative minor. But songs don't have to end on a key chord, they can fade out, like so many do.

Answer (score 3):

The "feel" of the ending not only depends on your last chord, but the way you approach it (the chord progression immediately before the end). If you want to finish your piece on a stable chord without using the tonic, a common progression is using the II chord before finishing on the dominant V. One of many combinations. Without a stable ending cadence, you're probably going to get some kind of vague or suspenseful feel. Which may or may not be what you're going for. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

The circular nature of most pop progressions start on the tonic and end the progression somewhere else so the progression may end somewhere else wanting to go back to the first chord. There are many, many examples of this and one I know of the top of my head is *When I Come Around* by Green Day.

The verse progression G D Em C and the last chord played is C, but it desperately wants to resolve back to a G and most covers I've seen of this song do eventually resolve back to the G after fanfare for that reason.

Now it's possible that you are perceiving B as the tonic, but based on the given information and having you always go back to G, I would bet G would sound more like the final resting place than Bm.

Comment: You were right....Actually,  my song is not in key of Bm ...its modal ...G lydian... heartly.thanks! !!!